# How do you extract a number from a URL as raw text?

Tags: google-sheets

So I have a list of Google+ profile links in a Google Sheet

> https://plus.google.com/112337650380234682548/

How can I extract the number on the end in a seperate column?

I've tried `=split(url,"/")` but that ends up formatting the numerical id in scientific notation and will not display it as text no matter what I try. Additionally I don't want the rest, just the last element.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With a `REGEXEXTRACT` formula you can do the following.

### Formula

```
A1 = https://plus.google.com/112337650380234682548/
=REGEXEXTRACT(A1, "\d+")
```

### Explained

The REGEX (`\d+`) searches for numbers only; d == numbers and + == all instances.

### Screenshot

[image]

### Note

The `REGEXEXTRACT` formula returns a string. The `SPLIT` formula however returns a formatted value, in your case a number existing of 21 digits. Google Sheets can only handle numbers up to 15 digits. The rest of the digits are being set to zero and a scientific notation is chosen.

### Example

I've created an example file for you: **[SPLIT vs. REGEXEXTRACT](https://docs.google.com/a/jacobjantuinstra.nl/spreadsheets/d/1wMJIKj2kD5B0oxmJmeCpZP2wKVXmibjF8n2QkeHpHqc/edit?usp=sharing)**

Comment: Cheers this works, Can you explain why it works as opposed to split? I was very confused and may help others later.

Comment: @RyanTheLeach See my revised answer.